# What do you call someone who is good at their job?

Tags: vocabulary

What do you call someone who is good at their job? For example: how would you describe an optometrist/ophthalmologist who is really good at what they do?

Comment: He is an excellent optometrist.  He is a skilled ophthalmologist.  She is a first-rate optometrist.  She is really good at what she does (which is ophthalmology).

Comment: _Competent_ is what you call anyone who is good at anything.

Comment: @JohnLawler - But note that *competent* is often used sarcastically, or to indicate that the individual "meets minimum requirements" but little more.

Comment: It's subject to Gricean interpretation; i.e, if the best thing you can truthfully say is "competent", it must not be a glowing recommendation. But that applies to any non-superlative.

Comment: How about 'top-drawer', 'top-notch', or these days, often simply 'top' (as in [*top model*](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=top+model))

Comment: You may refer to an *acknowledged/recognized/proven   professional/specialist/expert*.

Answer (score 2):

**Expert**—either as a noun:

> - A person who has a comprehensive and authoritative knowledge of or skill in a particular area [[ODO]](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/expert)
> - a person who has special skill or knowledge relating to a particular subject [[M-E]](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/expert)

Or as an adjective:

> - Having or involving authoritative knowledge [ODO]
> - having or showing special skill or knowledge because of what you have been taught or what you have experienced [M-E]

Answer (score 1):

A couple of mildly informal adjectives for describing exceptional competence are *crack* and *crackerjack*:

**crack** (adj.)

> 1. Highly trained and competent.
>      *Even a crack team of investigators would have trouble solving this case.*
>
>    2. Excellent, first-rate, superior, top-notch.
>         *She's a crack shot with that rifle.*

([Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/crack))

**crackerjack** (adj.)

> 1. Exceptionally fine or excellent; top-notch; high quality.
>
>    2. Expert, top-rated or high-performing.

([Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/crackerjack#English))

An example from an Ngram search:

> I had an able staff in the District of Columbia Committee and with personnel like Mr. Malone, who came to us from the city government, and there was a crackerjack lawyer who was completely devoted to doing his job in the District.

[(Department of the Interior and related agencies appropriations for fiscal year 1970: Hearings before a subcommittee of the Committee on Appropriations, United States Senate, Ninety-first Congress, first session, on H.R. 12781, Part 1)](https://books.google.com/books?id=jwk3AQAAIAAJ&q=%22crackerjack%20lawyer%22&dq=%22crackerjack%20lawyer%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=8UyhVa-XMcm3ogSDq7v4Dg&ved=0CFEQ6AEwBw)

Answer (score 1):

A "Master".
Especially for trades.

Master Goldsmith.

Master Coder.

Comment: Hello, Your answer was automatically flagged as low-quality for its length and content. The word *master* can have many different meanings. Can you expand your answer to cite a dictionary definition or example sentences?

Answer (score 0):

[Professional](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/professional) is an appropriate  way to refer to someone who is very competent in his job:

> - Worthy of or appropriate to a professional person; competent, skilful, or assured:
>
>   - *his professional expertise
>       their music is both memorable and professional*

(ODO)

- a very professional optometrist/ophthalmologist.

Comment: Yes, but it chiefly signifies that the activity is a paid one, and secondarily it is largely a class signifier.

Answer (score 0):

"**Proficient**" is defined by Merriam-Webster as "good at doing something", and "well advanced in an art, occupation, or branch of knowledge".